# Mobile Menu not working on TwentyThirteen child theme

Tags: mobile, theme-twenty-thirteen

I have customised the Twenty Thirteen wordpress theme with a child theme but the mobile menu does not expand when pressed. I have removed all the styles from the child theme to see if anything I have implemented was causing the issue but even with the styles of the parent Twenty Thirteen theme the mobile menu does not expand. I have deactivated all plugins and again this did not help. Could really use some help with this as I am at a loss.

The site I'm working on is http://tappingtherapyplus.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is code from the codex which enables your child inheritance.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
```